# A Mifare Classic 1K NFC Tag cannot be made read-only, while a Mifare Ultralight can - why?

Tags: nfc

I just discovered that and am wondering why the

Ndef.canMakeReadOnly()

call returns false on a Mifare 1K but true on a Ultrlight. I was hoping the 1K not only holds more data, but also has at least the same features as Ultralight.

Is there a way to achieve read-only for Mifare Classics? How is this done with the Ultralights, is this a NDEF standard?

Thx!

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but are you sure you want to use Mifare Classic? Its security is flawed and has been broken completely by [these researchers](http://www.sos.cs.ru.nl/applications/rfid/main.html), following previous successful attacks by other groups.

Comment: Thanx for your response. I am not at all in favor of the classics, but it seems to be the most used NFC tag right now. The others I know are Ultralight and Ultralight C - what others shoudl I consoder (NFC-Forum compatible)

Answer (score 2):

You can make your Mifare Classic tags read only by writing a B-Key in the sector trailers that only you know. Leave the A-Keys as the standard NDEF keys.

Comment: Thanx for your answer, this is really the most helpful so far. But what exactly does it mean to write the B key? Would I still write the NDEF message like I used to, e.g. usign the NDEF or NDEFFormatable classes and then use the MifareClassic Tag Tech class to somehow do some magic with the B key? Does this anyhow change the way I have to read the tag or does reading stay completely the same?

Answer (score 2):

Mifare Classic is not an NFC Forum tag while Mifare Ultralight is.

> For guaranteed compatibility across all Android devices with NFC, it is recommended to use NFC Forum Types 1-4 in new deployments of NFC tags with NDEF payload. Vendor NDEF formats will not work on all Android devices.

May be the Mifare Classic spec from NXP and the MifareClassic API (android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic) might help

A solution here: 
[How can I protect a Mifare Classic Tag that contains a NDEF message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6022834/how-can-i-protect-a-mifare-classic-tag-that-contains-a-ndef-message)