# How can I protect a Mifare Classic Tag that contains a NDEF message?

Tags: android, nfc

It's easy to protect a Mifare Ultralight with Android, there is the `Ndef.makeReadonly()` method for that. But Mifare Classic tags return `Ndef.canMakeReadonly() == false`, so this is not possible. I heard that one can make such a tag readonly or at least protect it with a key by setting the a or b keys.

There's this methid in MifareClassic tech: `authenticateSectorWithKeyB(int sectorIndex, byte[] key)`

Does anyone know if this can be used to make a ndef message on a mifare classic tag read-only? Or how else could I write a ndef message onto the tag and then somehow lock it against new writes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible using the authenticate methods.

First, here is the datasheet for the Mifare Classic 4k:

http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S703x.pdf

The important chapters for your are:

- 3.6 Memory Organization
- 3.6.3 Sector Trailer

In short a write protection works like this:

The Mifare Classic is divided into sectors of 4*16 bytes each (only applies to the first 1k or so... the higher blocks are a bit different, but thats documented in the spec). Of these 64 bytes 16 are used for authentication/protection. For each sector of the card you do the following:

1. Authenticate the sector using KeyA
2. Read the sector trailer.
3. Modify the access bits of the sector trailer.
4. Write the sector trailer back to the card.

The KeyA values for Mifare Classics are:

> byte[] KEY_DEFAULT =
>     {(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF,(byte)0xFF};

For unformatted, factory fresh cards.

> byte[] KEY_MIFARE_APPLICATION_DIRECTORY =
>     {(byte)0xA0,(byte)0xA1,(byte)0xA2,(byte)0xA3,(byte)0xA4,(byte)0xA5};

For the first sector of the card

> byte[] KEY_NFC_FORUM =
>   {(byte)0xD3,(byte)0xF7,(byte)0xD3,(byte)0xF7,(byte)0xD3,(byte)0xF7};

For all other sectors.

Important: You have to write back the original KeyA keys to the card. If these differ from the keys shown above the card will not be Ndef compliant anymore.

For the modified access bits you have two choices:

1. Only enable Read for KeyA. This will give you a 100% write protection that can't be revoked.
2. Enable Read for KeyA and Read/Write for KeyB. Also store a secret key in KeyB. This will allow you to authenticate a write protected sector using your secret KeyB to unprotect the card.

Background: Android will only authenticate a Ndef formatted tag using the KeyA values shown above. The Ndef detection code never tries KeyB on its own, therefore you can use KeyB for your own purposes.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. While this may surely work, I find it really complicated. Does anyone know if support for password-protecting tags liek with makeReadOnly() will also come for Mifare Tags in future (e.g. a future Android release?) OR does anyone know of libraries out there that would do this?

Comment: Good answer, can ndef data be written and read from multiple protected blocks through normal ndef read and write? Ndef.writeNdefMessage to write and using getNdefMessage to get the message?